# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.spark_project.guava.collect.MapMaker

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, spring-boot, guava

I am trying to integrate apache spark with spring-boot cassandra project. But while running the project it gives following error:

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spark_project/guava/collect/MapMaker] with root cause
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.spark_project.guava.collect.MapMaker
```

I checked my maven dependencies and the mapmaker file was present there in the spark-network-common_2.11.jar within 'org/spark_project/guava/collect/'. 
Here is the pom file dependencies I am using:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common -->
    <!-- <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency> -->


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-mapping -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId> <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId> 
        <version>3.5.0</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The spark-network-common_2.11.jar comes along with the spark-core dependency, still I tried to add it separately, but even that didn't work. 
What could be the problem that spring-boot can't identify the mapmaker file at runtime?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The package path of "org.spark_project.guava.collect.MapMaker" Heavily implies that the guava package has been relocated into the spark_project in order to avoid dependency hell.

Things like this are controlled by the build process, and can be easily overlooked sources of incompatibility between libraries.

My instinct is that you may be using mis-matching versions of libraries, that whilst technically may be compatible, arn't because of guava being relocated differently.

You have

```
   <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.10</artifactId>
```

Commented out, when the other dependencies have 2.11 listed.

These represent the version numbers of the Scala Language+runtime used and should match across any projects that use Scala.

Which class / library is attempting to load the relocated Guava? This should give you a large hint towards which library is potentially outdated/mismatched.